# Как правильно обрабатывать ответы PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Помогите разобраться, как сообщить объекту PDOStatement, что бы тот отдал при SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN массив, а при остальных TRUE или FALSE?
Ниже приведу метод который я использую для SELECT.

```
class Database extends Api
{
    public $settings = [
        'host'      => '',
        'name'      => '',
        'user'      => '',
        'pass'      => ''
    ];

    private $pdo = null;

    public function query ( $string )
    {
        $response = null;

        if ( !$this->settings['host'] || !$this->settings['name'] || !$this->settings['user'] || !$this->settings['pass'] || !$string )
            return $response;
        elseif ( !$this->pdo )
            $this->pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host='. $this->settings['host'] .';dbname='. $this->settings['name'], $this->settings['user'], $this->settings['pass'] );

        $response = $this->pdo->query( $string );

        if ( !$response ) return false;

        $response->rows = [];
        while( $row = $response->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){ $response->rows[] = $row; }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Руками.
Используя **средства, которые предоставляет PDO.**

Для этого надо рассматривать ПДО не в качестве примитивной замены примитивному API mysql или mysqli, а в качестве того, чем она является на самом деле - почти полноценной абстракции для доступа к БД.

В первую очередь надо понять две вещи

1. Что PDO предназначена для работы с **подготовленными выражениями.** Что автоматом делает функцию `query` бессмысленной и вредной, если она не принимает вторым параметром массив с данными для запроса.
2. Что PDO умеет возвращать данные в **десятках различных форматов,** включая и простой вложенный массив.

Функция query должна выглядеть так:

```
public function query ( $sql, $params = [] )
{
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->execute( $params );
    return $stmt;
}
```

Здесь мы

- весь кошмар с коннектом вынесли в **конструктор**
- в ужасе избавились от переменной $response, которой в принципе не должно быть в классе, работающем с БД. Смотрим, как устроена сама PDO, мотаем на ус.
- добавили необязательный массив $params с данными для подготовленного запроса
- возвращаем statement, чтобы потом, используя method chaining получить нужный результат.

И вот этот стейтмент и надо опрашивать на предмет нужной информации. Примеры:

Кейс для изначального варианта для query():

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table")->fetchAll();
```

здесь мы явно говорим ПДО, в каком формате хотим получить данные. Это гораздо лучше, чем определить только один примитивный формат и потом мучаться с ним.

Кейс для случая, который вовсе не был предусмотрен автором вопроса, даже в теории, в котором мы получаем количесвто обновленных строк:

```
$stmt = $db->query("UPDATE t SET f =? WHERE id =?", [$data, $id]);
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Кейсы для множества других случаев, также не предусмотренных вышеприведенным кодом, таких как получение значения единственного поля, единственной колонки и многих других форматов

```
$name = $db->query("SELECT name FROM t WHERE id=?", [$id])->fetchColumn();
$col = $db->query("SELECT name FROM t")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$dic = $db->query("SELECT id, name FROM t")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

и так далее.

В общем, надо выучить [как правильно работать с PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo), и начать применять эту библиотеку правильно.

Comment: Ясно, для решения тривиального вопроса, я должен использовать кучу разных методов, для разного типа данных писать разные условия. К примеру для UPDATE использовать rowCount(), для SELECT использовать fetch() или fetchAll(), если за оперативкой не следить. Хочешь банан? Получай Гориллу с бананом. PHP и дизайн языка. Картина маслом... Тем не менее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Я хотел бы заметить, что ваш вариант в принципе не предусматривает экономного расхода памяти. В правильном же вариенте получаем стейтмент и делаем `foreach($stmt as $row)...` - и память расходуется экономно.

Comment: По поводу же "кучи разных методов" - это лучше, чем некая магия, которая доложна сама догадываться, что от нее ждут. В столовой, к примеру, приходится использовать ложку, вилку, чашку, тарелку, солонку, поднос, чайник... Конечно, можно и одним корытом обойтись, но с *кучей разных методов* как-то удобнее ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
 if ( !$this->settings['host'] || !$this->settings['name'] || !$this->settings['user'] || !$this->settings['pass'] || !$string )
        return $response;
    elseif ( !$this->pdo )
        $this->pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host='. $this->settings['host'] .';dbname='. $this->settings['name'], $this->settings['user'], $this->settings['pass'] );
```

Интересно а как ошибки обрабатывать

Напиши разные методы insert() select() и т.д. и один гетер.

Comment: Ошибки никак не надо обрабатывать. Ошибки обрабатывает PHP, и прекрасно с этим справляется. Методы insert() select()  и т.д. никакого смысла не несут, поскольку уже есть функция query, которая прекрасно может исполнить эти запросы.