# Метод для PDO для подключения к базе и исполнения

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo

Задача: написать метод, который будет при вызове возвращать true/false или массив из базы. 
Я в классе прописал вот такой метод, но он не работает:

```
    public function queryExec($sql, $data=false, $execOnly=false) {

    $stmt = $this->getCon()->prepare($sql);

    if ($execOnly){
        $result = $stmt->execute(); // Возвращает в массив
    } else {

        $data = array_filter($data);

        if (!is_array($data) || count($data) < 1) {
            //throw new Exception("you got error!", 1);
            $stmt->execute();
        } else {
            $stmt->execute($data);
        }

        $result = $stmt->fetch();
    }

    return $result;
}

private function users_online(){

    if (session_id() == '')  session_start();

    $session    = session_id();
    $curTime    = time();
    $timeout    = $curTime - 60; // Время 
    $ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_online` (
    `session` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `time` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

    $this->queryExec($sql, false, true);

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(time) FROM users_online WHERE session = ?";

    $result = $this->queryExec($sql, [$session], false);


    // Добавление или обновления - пользователя на сайте
    if (count($result) > 0){
        $sql = "UPDATE users_online SET time='?', ip='?' WHERE session = '?'";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users_online (time, ip, session) VALUES ('?', '?', '?')";
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE users_online SET time='?', ip='?' WHERE session = '?'";


    $data['time']   = $curTime;
    $data['ip']     = $ip;
    $data['session'] = $session;

    $result = $this->queryExec($sql, $data, false);

    //var_dump(count($result));

    if (!$result){
        $this->errors[] = "SQL ошибка при проверке пользователей на сайте!";
        return -1;
    }

    $sql = "DELETE FROM users_online WHERE time < ?";

    $this->queryExec($sql, [$timeout], false);

    // Смотрим сколько пользователей на сайте

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_online";

    $result = $this->queryExec($sql, false, true);

    if (!$result)
        return -1;
    else {
        var_dump($result);
        return $r[0];
    }

}
```

метод queryExec планируется использовать везде во всех классах, которые будут наследоваться от класса подключения к базе данных.

Помогите исправить ошибку. Выдает примерно вот это:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/connection.php:66 Stack trace: #0 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/connection.php(66): PDOStatement->fetch() #1 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/connection.php(108): 
>   Connection->queryExec('UPDATE users_on...', Array, false) #2 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/connection.php(38): Connection->users_online() #3 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/login.php(37): Connection->Connection() #4 {main} thrown in /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/connection.php on line 66

Самое интересное то, что до использования массивов в users_online() в queryExec() все срабатывает, а когда вводится массив $data выдает ошибку.

UPD!

Ошибка вылетает в другом месте с тем же PDO не че все не так

код вот такой:

```
            for ($i=0; $i < rand(1,6); $i++) { 
            $authLoginData['randomHash'] = md5(md5(generateCode(rand(1,32).WEBSITESOLT)));
        }

        $sqls = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_hash`= ?,`user_last_visit`= ?, `user_ip`= ? WHERE user_id = ? ";

        $Ndata['hash_']         = $authLoginData['randomHash'];
        $Ndata['visit_']        = time();
        $Ndata['ip_']           = $this->filteringData($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
        $Ndata['id_']           = intval($result['user_id']);

        $resultat = $this->queryExec($sql, $Ndata)->fetch();

        // Проверяем, если SQL код не исполнился выводим ошибку!
        if (!$resultat) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->lang['error_SQL_update_data'];
            return false;
        } else {

            $this->errors['first'] = $this->lang['welcome_msg'];
```

В запросе выдает ошибку

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/connection.php:73 Stack trace: #0 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/connection.php(73): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/users.class.php(71): Connection->queryExec('SELECT `user_id...', Array) #2 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/controllers/loginController.php(27): Users->loginAction() #3 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/routers/loginRoute.php(11): LoginController->loginAction() #4 /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/login.php(31): require_once('/Users/userName/Si...') #5 {main} thrown in /Users/userName/Sites/board_php/classes/connection.php on line 73

WTF?????

Comment: Уберите последний `$sql = "UPDATE users_online SET time='?', ip='?' WHERE session = '?'";`

Comment: удалил все равно выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Начнем с того что, [как я уже говорил раньше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484408/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-php-pdo), как сам код, так и подход в целом не имеют смысла. Даже в том виде, в котором эта функция нужна автору впопроса, она должна выглядеть как

```
public function queryExec($sql, $data=false, $execOnly=false)
{
    $stmt = $this->getCon()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    if ($execOnly){
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Но даже и в этом виде она не нужна, поскольку наличие последнего параметра попросту не имеет смысла.

Во-первых, возвращать true или false нет смысла. TRUE будет всегда. поскольку в случае ошибки будет брошено исключение, и функция просто не успеет ничего вернуть.
Во-вторых, функция должна возвращать не fetchAll() (и уж тем более не fetch(), который совем не пришей кобыле хвост. Что делать за просами, которые возвращают больше одной строки?), **а стейтмент**. Из которого потом можно получить любой из **десятков вариантов результатов**, которые может вернуть пдо. То есть, функция на самом деле должна выглядеть вот так:

```
public function queryExec($sql, $data=false)
{
    $stmt = $this->getCon()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Соотетственно, обращаться к этой функции надо в зависимости от того, какой результат от нее ждут:

```
# just exec
$this->queryExec($sql);
$this->queryExec($sql, $data);

# all rows
$result = $this->queryExec($sql, $data);
foreach ($result as $row) echo $row['name'];

# one row
$row = $this->queryExec($sql, $data)->fetch();

# one cell
$count = $this->queryExec($sql)->fetchColumn();

# column
$ids = $this->queryExec($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

и так далее.

Далее.

Это не относится к вопросу напрямую, но создание таблицы при каждом обращении к функции мы в ужасе из нее уберем.

Теперь подравняем функцию. Не будем здесь рассказывать, как заменить три запроса на один, а просто сделаем код чуть более осмысленным с использованием вышеприведенной функции

```
private function users_online(){

    if (session_id() == '')  session_start();

    $session    = session_id();
    $curTime    = time();
    $timeout    = $curTime - 60; // Время 
    $ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users_online WHERE session = ?";
    $result = $this->queryExec($sql, [$session])->fetch();

    // Добавление или обновления - пользователя на сайте
    if ($result){
        $sql = "UPDATE users_online SET time=?, ip=? WHERE session = ?";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users_online (time, ip, session) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    }

    $this->queryExec($sql, [$curTime, $ip, $session]);

    $this->queryExec("DELETE FROM users_online WHERE time < ?", [$timeout]);

    return $this->queryExec("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_online")->fetchColumn();
}
```

Как можно заметить, помимо других улучшений, я убрал кавычки, стоявшие вокруг плейсхолдеров в запросах, а также пофиксил массив данных для запроса. Которые и были причиной самой маленькой из проблем этого кода.

И напоследок, в приложении не должно быть классов, которые будут наследоваться от класса подключения к базе данных. Объект этого класса должен передаваться в остальные классы в виде переменной в конструкторе.

**Update**

---

И совсем напоследок, главное правило, которые должен выучить человек, который хочет заниматься программированием:

При возникновении ошибки её надо прочитать. Это самый важный момент. Это позволит не гадать, что там с ПДО "не че все не так", а сразу узнать, что именно не так.

В данном случае мы сначала обращаемся к **трассировке** и видим, что проблема с запросом

```
SELECT `user_id`
```

а совсем не с

```
UPDATE users
```

После этого гуглим сообщение об ошибке и читаем, что проблема в [несовпадении количества плейсхолдеров в prepare() и переменных execute()](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/parameter_was_not_defined).

Кстати, после этой ошибки выдаст следующую, поскольку для запросов UPDATE fetch применять нельзя. а и сам код

```
    if (!$resultat) {
        $this->errors[] = $this->lang['error_SQL_update_data'];
        return false;
```

не имеет смысла. Как я уже говорил, в случае ошибки бросается исключение, и поэтому никаких `$this->errors[]` в коде быть не должно.

Comment: Молоток, спасибо большушее. Единственное, что не понял зачем SELECT 1 в  первом запросе. Первая ячейка?

Comment: Нет, это просто выборка константы, числа 1. Так пишут, когда нам неважно, какое поле выбирать. В данном случае count не нужен, поскольку предполагается, что на session стоит уникальный индекс. Кстати, при его наличии можно таки сменить три запроса на 1, убрав селект, и заменив инсерт на insert .. on duplicate key update.

Comment: не мог ты мне еще помочь?  вот с этим    $sqls = "UPDATE `users` SET `user_hash`= ?,`user_last_visit`= ?, `user_ip`= ? WHERE user_id = ? ";

   $Ndata['hash']    = $authLoginData['randomHash'];
   $Ndata['visit']   = time();
   $Ndata['ip']    = $this->filteringData($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
   $Ndata['id']    = intval($result['user_id']);

   var_dump($Ndata);

   $resultat = $this->queryExec($sql, $Ndata)->fetch();

Comment: Ничего не понял

Comment: Обновил в первом посте, там код.

Comment: Добавил ответ на эту проблему.